# ffmpeg: How to set a custom HTTP header when using PUT as the output method?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to use ffmpeg to PUT encoded files to object storage, and I need to include an API key in a header. I've tried `-http_opts '"headers='AccessKey: mykey'"` and `-headers 'AccessKey: mykey'` but neither end up with the header in the request when I use `-v trace` to see what is getting sent.

Here's the relevant part of my command:

```
-method PUT -headers 'AccessKey: mykey' \
https://storage/store/stream.mpd
```

Is this a known issue or have I just got the order of the options wrong?

Comment: Which version of FFmpeg are you using? And could you possibly post the whole command line or a comparable MRE, even if you needed to replace some file names with mocked ones?

Answer (score 2):

Your header is missing a trailing CRLF. Try `-headers 'AccessKey: mykey'$'\r\n'` with your ffmpeg version.

Newer ffmpeg versions have auto adding of trailing CRLF in headers and your code

`ffmpeg -v trace -headers 'AccessKey: mykey' -method PUT -i http://localhost/`

is working with my ffmpeg version 4.3.4-0+deb11u1+mx21+1 built with gcc 10 (Debian 10.2.1-6)